Error during android react native app bundling
I am using eas to create an .aab file so that i can publish my app on Google Play. I am using expo for the creation and a lot of expo modules. I am running this command in the root directory:
eas build --platform android
However i am getting an error during the Run Gradle process indicating that there is an error in the code of the expo-module-core. The error is an cpp file of the module. Specifically in the JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp. This is the error:
 /home/expo/workingdir/build/react/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/cpp/JavaScriptModuleObject.cpp:148:28: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'weak_ptr'
      auto weakConstructor = std::weak_ptr(constructor);

and this is the part of the code with the error
 for (auto &[name, classInfo]: classes) {
    auto &[classRef, constructor, ownerClass] = classInfo;
    auto classObject = classRef->cthis();
    auto weakConstructor = std::weak_ptr(constructor);

.
I found that the correct constructor for the weak_ptr has this format std::weak_ptr<ClassType> but i do not know how to apply it, as i have not written the cpp code myself
